# Simple Distributed Graph BGL Example

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, boost-graph

I am playing with the distributed Boost Graph Library, without success. My objective is very easy: distribute a graph generated by a BGL generator [from the examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/distributed_adjacency_list.html#where-defined). However, I have compilation errors regarding `bsp_process_group`:

The error list is **HUGE**, but basically says that my `typedef` is erroneous.

```
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/distributed/detail/mpi_process_group.ipp:137:8: No type named 'list' in namespace 'std'
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/distributed/detail/mpi_process_group.ipp:137:12: Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
/Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/scratch/pbgl/pbgl/main.cpp:17:68: No template named 'bsp_process_group' in namespace 'boost::parallel'; did you mean 'boost::process_group'?
/Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/scratch/pbgl/pbgl/main.cpp:17:85: No member named 'bsp_process_group' in namespace 'boost::parallel'; did you mean 'bsp_process_group_tag'?
/Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/scratch/pbgl/pbgl/main.cpp:17:116: Expected a type
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp:57:26: Type 'int' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp:58:26: Type 'int' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp:65:26: Type 'int' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp:66:26: Type 'int' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp:67:26: Type 'int' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/erdos_renyi_generator.hpp:48:67: Argument may not have 'void' type
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/erdos_renyi_generator.hpp:57:67: Argument may not have 'void' type
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/erdos_renyi_generator.hpp:87:24: Field has incomplete type 'vertices_size_type' (aka 'void')
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/erdos_renyi_generator.hpp:88:21: Field has incomplete type 'edges_size_type' (aka 'void')
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:253:9: Field has incomplete type 'void'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:254:9: Field has incomplete type 'void'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:262:19: Cannot form a reference to 'void'
```

Here's my very simple and erroneous code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/use_mpi.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/distributed/mpi_process_group.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/distributed/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/erdos_renyi_generator.hpp>
#include <boost/random/linear_congruential.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    boost::mpi::environment  env;
    boost::mpi::communicator comm;

    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::distributedS<boost::parallel::bsp_process_group, boost::vecS>, boost::directedS> graph;
    typedef boost::erdos_renyi_iterator<boost::minstd_rand, graph> generator;

    boost::minstd_rand gen;

    graph g(generator(gen, 100, 0.05), generator(), 100);

    if (comm.rank() == 0)
    {
        // print all nodes for rank 0 here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can you spot the error? Moreover, is there some place where I can find some source code to read? The distributed BGL documentation I find is very scarce...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the documentation has become out of date;  `boost::parallel::bsp_process_group` no longer seems to exist.  Using `boost::graph::distributed::mpi_process_group` instead as a replacement (plus adding `#include <map>`) allows this code to compile on my machine (Ubuntu 15.04 using Boost 1.59).